# Compute a pairwise function in R

Tags: r, matrix

For example I have a matrix 3x3, I want to apply a function that I made between [1,1]&&[1,2] then [1,1]&&[1,3] then [1,2]&&[1,3](a combination).

Then I go to the next row

This is an example of my matrix

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] -0.2 0.52 0.36
[2,] -0.2 0.66 0.50
[3,]  0.8 0.10 1.00
```

And I have to apply this function :

```
Fst <- function ( x,y ) {
  F = sd(c(x,y)) / (mean(c(x,y)) * (1-mean(c(x,y))))
  F  
}
```

Does any one know how to do this ??? Thank you in advance

Comment: I probably know how to do this, but the best approach obviously depends on the specific example (and the function you want to apply in particular).

Comment: Thank you @jogo, I am a newbie on stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want:

```
m <- matrix(c(-0.2, 0.52, 0.36,  -0.2, 0.66, 0.50,  0.8, 0.10, 1.00), 3, 3, byrow=TRUE)
m    
myfun <- function(x) {
  apply(combn(x,2), 2, function(x) sd(x) / mean(x) / (1-mean(x)) )
}
apply(m, 1, myfun)
# > apply(m, 1, myfun)
#           [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
# [1,] 3.7880720 3.433720 1.999898
# [2,] 5.3801603 3.882155 1.571348
# [3,] 0.4591602 0.464438 2.571297
```

`apply(m, 1, myfun)` works on each row (the results for the first row will be the first elements in the resulting matrix, i.e. in the first column). `combn(x,2)` produces the pairs - stored columnwise in a matrix, see `combn(11:15, 2)`. Another `apply()` is working on each column of that matrix.
I changed your function because `sd()` and `mean()` are working on vectors.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to loop over rows. You can do it efficiently for all of them at once if you vectorize your function. Use `Vectorize` if you don't want to change it.

```
m <- matrix(c(-0.2, -0.2, 0.8, 0.52, 0.66, 0.10, 0.36, 0.50, 1), 3)

library(matrixStats)
Fst_vectorized <- function ( x,y ) {
  X <- cbind(x, y)
  F = rowSds(X) / (rowMeans(X) * (1-rowMeans(X)))
  F  
}

Fst(m[1,1], m[1,2])
#[1] 3.788072

res <- combn(as.data.frame(m), 2, FUN = function(x) Fst_vectorized(x[[1]], x[[2]]))
colnames(res) <-  combn(seq_len(ncol(m)), 2, 
                        FUN = function(x) paste(x[[1]], x[[2]], sep = "vs"))
#         1vs2     1vs3      2vs3
#[1,] 3.788072 5.380160 0.4591602
#[2,] 3.433720 3.882155 0.4644380
#[3,] 1.999898 1.571348 2.5712974
```

Comment: Thank you !!!! When I try to add colnames I have this error    'Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("1vs2", "1vs3", "2vs3")) : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent'

Comment: This code as given runs without errors. If you get an error you have changed something.